# Cluster IP is not updated with latest endpoint IPs after pods restarts due to helm upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-statefulset

I am making helm upgrade of the chart which resulted in statefulsets to go for restart resulting in the change in IP of the pods but the cluster ip service is not restarted during helm upgrade this results in endpoint ips of restarted pods not being updated into the cluster ip service, hence any attempt to reach the pods immediately after pod comes up via service ip will result in a failure. But same can be done after few seconds, any solution for this?

Comment: Maybe thats because apps didnt became fully ready but kubernetes start sending traffic to them. You might need to define readiness probe to your statefull applications. 

for example if it is mysql app you can define something like that.
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            # Check we can execute queries over TCP (skip-networking is off).
            command: ["mysql", "-h", "127.0.0.1", "-e", "SELECT 1"]